# HangFire recurring jobs on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I started using HangFire to process a task every X minutes/hours and I need to add recurring jobs. In console application I managed to do it just fine but on asp.net I can only get it to work once, through the BackgroundJob.Enqueue method.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private static string LigacaoBD = myConn;
    private static ApiMethods sportRadar = new ApiMethods();
    private static Jogo jogo = new Jogo(LigacaoBD);
    private static List<SportRadar.ClassesCliente.Jogo> jogos;
    private static List<SportRadar.ClassesCliente.Competicao> competicoes;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(LigacaoBD);

        using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
        {
            foreach (var recurringJob in connection.GetRecurringJobs())
            {
                RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(recurringJob.Id);
            }
        }

        using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
        {
            // This works just fine
            var id=BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Actualizacoes());
            // This does not.
            // I even checked the DB for job queue or something but couldn't find anything
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(id, () => Actualizacoes(), Cron.Minutely);
        }
    }



    public void Actualizacoes()
    {
        // Stuff I need to do regularly
    }
}
```

I thought I got it right but evidently I got something wrong here. Where do you think the problem might be at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two problems.

One. because you're passing `id` in - which is unnecessary in your implementation.

`BackgroundJob.Enqueue` returns a unique identifier for a job. In your code, this job has already been queued and executed.

Change

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(id, () => Actualizacoes(), Cron.Minutely);
```

to

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Actualizacoes(), Cron.Minutely);
```

Also, you're wrapping the creation of `BackgroundJobServer` in a `using` statement. Then creating the job in there. Therefore, the `BackgroundJobServer` is being cleared up by GC.

Instead, try this:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private static string LigacaoBD = myConn;
    private static ApiMethods sportRadar = new ApiMethods();
    private static Jogo jogo = new Jogo(LigacaoBD);
    private static List<SportRadar.ClassesCliente.Jogo> jogos;
    private static List<SportRadar.ClassesCliente.Competicao> competicoes;

    private BackgroundJobServer _backgroundJobServer;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(LigacaoBD);

        using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
        {
            foreach (var recurringJob in connection.GetRecurringJobs())
            {
                RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(recurringJob.Id);
            }
        }

        //create an instance of BackgroundJobServer
        _backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer();

        //add your recurring job
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Actualizacoes(), Cron.Minutely);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it. But still only executes once.

Comment: Ok, changed it and got nothing. But then I added BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Actualizacoes()); between _backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(); and RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Actualizacoes(), Cron.Minutely); and it worked. It seems you first have to create it bafore you can update it. Makes sense. Edit you answer so I can accept it. And big thanks! :)

Comment: you  shouldn't need to use `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` at all in your case

Comment: Oh, you're right. Didn't wait long enough for the breakpoint to be hit and the job to be created on the DB. :)